# writeDynamic in Apache Beam on EMR/Spark is not finishing writes to S3, leaves out temp files

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-beam, amazon-emr, apache-beam-io

I have a bounded PCollection and would like to persist the output to S3 bucket with dynamic file naming scheme. Unfortunately, when running on EMR (tried emr-6.2.0 and emr-5.30.1) & Spark Runner, after all steps in the pipeline finish and cluster terminates, output on S3 contains only some of expected contents in main output directory, most of it though is placed in .temp-beam folder and never moved to the main output dir. Most of it = 90% of expected lines are not persisted in correctly named files and spot checks indicate the expected lines are in files inside .temp-beam folder.
Here's a relevant pipeline declaration part:

```
PCollection<SomeObject> input; // is a bounded PCollection   
                     
FileIO.Write<String, SomeObject> write = FileIO.<String, SomeObject>writeDynamic()
                    .by(SomeObject::key)
                    .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                    .withCompression(Compression.GZIP)
                    .withNaming((SerializableFunction<String, FileIO.Write.FileNaming>) key
                            -> (FileIO.Write.FileNaming) (window, pane, numShards, shardIndex, compression)
                            -> String.format("some_object_%s_%d.csv.gz", key, shardIndex))
                    .via(Contextful.fn(SomeObject::toCsvLine), Contextful.fn(x -> TextIO.sink().withHeader(SomeObject.HEADER)))
                    .to("s3://some-bucket/some-output-path");

input.apply("write-a-pcollection", write);
```

With this code I get an S3 bucket that looks like:

- some_object_key1_0.csv.gz
- some_object_key1_1.csv.gz
- some_object_key2_0.csv.gz
- some_object_key3_0.csv.gz
- .temp-beam-<uuid> with 90% of the expected content persisted inside objects named with random uuids

However, when I add `.withIgnoreWindowing()` to the writeDynamic configuration, output seems to be fully correct and no .temp-beam directory is left over. This method is deprecated though and no replacement has been ever provided in the javadocs (at least I couldn't find any).

Why does this writer needs to ignore windowing to function properly in this case and how the pipeline should look like in order not to utilize `.withIgnoreWindowing()`?

**UPDATE**:

Tried to add a global windowing step right before writeDynamic was applied (as suggested in comments), but no luck:

```
input.apply("wnd", Window.<SomeObject>into(new GlobalWindows())
     .triggering(DefaultTrigger.of()))
```

Comment: Do you have some windowing scheme set up before this transform? Presumably if the problem is entirely due to windowing, you can get equivalent behavior by setting the window on the input to the global window with the default trigger (as described in [the method's documentation](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.25.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.Write.html#withIgnoreWindowing--)).

Comment: No windowing in the collection before that. That's what my colleague suggested after I posted the question. Will try and post results here.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work (see edited post). I think my issue may be with the windowing inside writeDynamic, but it exceeds my knowledge of Beam.

Comment: After diving into the related code some more, I suspect this might be a bug, most likely something related to [FinalizeDestination](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/243128a8fc52798e1b58b0cf1a271d95ee7aa241/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileBasedSink.java#L601) and its differing behavior with/without windows. I suggest making a bug report on the [Beam Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM) with components "io-java-files" and "runner-spark" (in case this is runner-specific).

Comment: I should also mention that in my investigation I found no other way to specify that behavior other than the `.withIgnoreWindowing()` method, so it seems you're likely stuck with this as a workaround for now.

Comment: Thanks for your investigation, filed a bug on Jira: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-12202